# ROS Navigation Stack on Kuka Youbot

Tags: ros, navigation, youbot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I found the youbot-navigation pakcage on the ROS Homepage: wiki.ros.org/youbot_navigation

It mentions functionalities (for example the slam.launch) which are not included in the default navigation package included in the youbot-ros-pkg: github.com/youbot/youbot-ros-pkg.

Where can I find this package (as nothing is mentioned in the wiki article) and is the package for Ros Fuerte or Groovy?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/128976/ros-navigation-stack-on-kuka-youbot/) by [Jabro](https://answers.ros.org/users/9246/jabro/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2014-02-13

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Hamid](https://answers.ros.org/users/18987/hamid/) on 2014-07-03**:
Hi, I'm trying to run the SLAM on youbot.. I'm having hard time on dealing with Costmaps parameters and Amcl... could you please help me? could you bring up the SLAM on this robot? or in rviz?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The code lives here for that version: https://github.com/WPI-RAIL/youbot_navigation which is for Groovy.

---

Originally posted by [rtoris288](https://answers.ros.org/users/982/rtoris288/) with karma: 1173 on 2014-02-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0